# Magento 2 how to create custom index.php and pass store code programmatically?

Tags: magento2, stores, index.php

I have a multi-vendor e-commerce platform, everytime I create a new store I need to create a folder for the store and include an index.php

for example:

```
var/www/html/magento/stores/store2/index.php
```

Inside the index.php I add the store code like this:

```
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'store2_code'; //this is the important line
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

How could I programmatically create an index.php file and add the store code?
Currently I know how to create the store programmatically, but just the index.php is missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To create a file programmatically you can go with below two approaches.

### **Approach - I**

```
$myfile = fopen("index.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "your content";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

### **Approach - II**

You can use system command to create file.

```
shell_exec('touch index.php');
```